# JUnit testing with multiple test cases in a method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a following class A with a constructor that takes two strings as parameters.

```
Class A
{
String test1;
String test2;

    public(String test1, String test2)
    {
    this.test1 = test1;
    this.test2 = test2;
    }
}
```

I would like to test a constructor with three test cases within a one test case method i.e. 
1. Null test1
2. Null test2
3. Null test1, Null test2

```
String test1 = "ABC";
String test2 = "XYZ";
@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
public void testNullConstructorValues() {
       new A(null, test2);
       new A(test1, null);
       new A(null, null);
}
```

The problem here is that after first constructor declaration, the method throws NPE and returns out of the method. I would like the method to execute all 3 constructor declarations  within just one method and perform the expected exception check.

Is there any way to do this of doing all 3 test cases within one method?

Comment: Is this just for curiosity ? Otherwise you have just only three cases possible, so that won't do much more work if you create 3 separate methods for each case.

Comment: No it's just for curiosity. Its just a mock, I have a bunch of test case method within my class and I was wondering if I could group the few test cases by any means to be more readable?

Comment: I really recommend you don't do this.  Keep each test scenario in its own method, so that if a test fails, you can see immediately from the JUnit output which one it is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a [Parameterized runner](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) test.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ATest {
    private String value1;
    private String value2;

    private static final String ABC = "abc";
    private static final String XYZ = "xyz";

    public ATest(String value1, String value2) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    @Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
    public void nullPassedToConstructor() {
         A a = new A(value1, value2);
    }

    // Provide data
    @Parameters
    public static List<Object[]> data() {
    List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

        list.add(new Object[] {null, XYZ});
        list.add(new Object[] {ABC, null});
        list.add(new Object[] {null, null});

        return list;
    }
}
```